# Graph of a general region

Tags: graphs

I am looking for some code on how to plot the region bounded by x=0, x=1, y=0, y=1, and z=xy for some z. Basically just a graph of the unit square with vertices (0,0), (0, 1), (1,0), (1,1) with the top right corner cut out by z=xy.

Any help appreciated, I am extremely new to latex.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={0, 0.7, 1}, ytick={0, 0.7,1}];
\addplot[domain=0.7:1]{0.7/x};
\addplot[domain=0:0.7]{1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `pgfplots` package?  Questions here should usually show what code you have tried to use.

Comment: I edited my current code in. It doesn't look right and I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: A minimal working example would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plot may not look right because you do not show the full range of y. To fix that, add `ymin=0`. By adding the other min and max values, you can also condense it to one instead of two plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xtick={0, 0.7, 1}, ytick={0, 0.7,1},xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1];
  \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=101]{0.7/x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further options include using a contour plot

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis, view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3 [domain=0:1,samples=101,
            contour filled={
                levels={0.7}
            },
        ] {x*y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]